# How to get a list of running services in Android?

Tags: android, list, service

How can I get a list of running services in android code and send it via SMS using `SMSManager`?

Comment: Please show what you have done. Here we are not code makers.Wanna some code go for free lancing site.

Comment: Getting answer on a question which doesn't shows any efforts directly asking for codes. This type of question has to be discouraged according to stackoverflow policy. I don't know why people are answering this type of questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Include the following permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

This method shows both tasks:

```
public void sendSMS {
    // This is the code to find the running services
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> rs = am.getRunningServices(50);
    String message = null;

    for (int i=0; i<rs.size(); i++) {
        ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo rsi = rs.get(i);
        Log.i("Service", "Process " + rsi.process + " with component " + rsi.service.getClassName());
        message =message+rsi.process ;
    }

    //This is the code to send sms.
    String phoneNumber = "0123456789";
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
}
```

The method detail.

```
public void sendTextMessage(String destinationAddress, String scAddress, String text, PendingIntent sentIntent, PendingIntent deliveryIntent)
```

Comment: The previous code to get a list of running service is working.Just add the code to send sms.

Comment: it is working but how can i format it like a list such as one by one and then send it

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this :

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> rs = am.getRunningServices(50);

for (int i=0; i<rs.size(); i++) {
  ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo
  rsi = rs.get(i);
  Log.i("Service", "Process " + rsi.process + " with component " + rsi.service.getClassName());
}
```

Comment: do we need any permission to do that? list is returning empty

Comment: @SaddaHussain That API is not available since Android 6.0 for privacy reasons. It will just return the running services for those that belong to the caller package

Answer (score 5):

Just like that:

```
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
      String serv = service.service.getClassName();
}
```